# Changing colors in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
F8HET <- ggplot(F8HET_phate) + 
  geom_point(aes(PHATE1, PHATE2, color=e2f_F8HET@active.ident)) +
  labs(color = "Cluster") + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c() + 
  ggtitle("F8HET")
```

and no matter what I put in scale_fill_virdis_c() the colors don't change.  Any ideas why or how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You should use `scale_color_viridis_c` because you are using the `color` aesthetic

Comment: When I do that I get the error:
```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Comment: Can you provide your data? A reproducible example would be helpful

Comment: According to the error message you are mapping a discrete variable on `color` in which case `scale_colour_viridis_d()` seems more appropriate.